# Can we have a translation for the list views similar to how we alternate News Pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, administration, language

I have a private team site >> and i enabled 2 languages "English" + "Arabic", as follow:-

[image]

where we are able to create new pages and translate them. but can we do the same thing for the list views? to change the list views columns names/titles based on the user language selection ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Per my knowledge and test, there is no option to translate columns names in the list views based on the user language selection.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply. so in this case the only option we have is to change the preferred language for the user from english to Araib, so the list views columns will be in Arabic ?

Comment: You can use the translations that come with your browser.